# How to update a category after update a post in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields, taxonomy-terms

I have a custom post type named **Beaches**. A category is created every time a post is created, this is working.

My category has the same title and the same slug as the post type.

The problem is when a post is updated, I can't link the post to the category anymore, if the title and the slug changes.

This code works to create a category:

```
function rci_custom_dynamic_beach_category ($post_id) {
  $post = get_post($post_id);

  if($post->post_status === 'auto-draft') return;
  if($post->post_type !== 'beaches') return;

  // Verify if the category exists already
  $exist = term_exists($post->post_name, 'beaches');

  if($exist !== 0 && $exist !== null) {

    // THE PROBLEM IS HERE

    // Get the category by the slug field
    $term = get_term_by('slug', $post->post_name, 'beaches');
    wp_update_term($term->term_id, 'beaches', array(
      'name' => $post->post_title,
      'slug' => $post->post_name
    ));
  }
  else {
    wp_insert_term($post->post_title, 'beaches', $args = array(
      'slug' => $post->post_name,
      'parent' => 'houses'
    ));
  }
} 

add_action('save_post', 'rci_custom_dynamic_beach_category');
```

Is there a way to get the old slug value in order to find the term before the post update with the new values?

Comment: if you update the title, every thing will change, it will be like you have created a new entry.

Comment: Yes, you're right. And I need to figure out how to manage that, because it will lose the reference if I create the category again.

Comment: Why not create a separate table in the db that stores the old slugs and terms for it? Then when a post is updated, you just grab the terms by the post_id and update accordingly?

Comment: Could be an idea, and from your idea I could perform another approach, @Kyon147. I'm saving the post ID inside the slug, because I'm not going to use it. This way I can update the title and maintain the link between the post and the category.